# jQuery datetimepicker - The mouse is captured while selecting time

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, mousecapture

I have a page with a DateTimePicker attached to a textbox. The problem is that the mouse is captured by the hour slider button when I open datetimepicker and click on the hour (or minute) slider button. The capture is not released even if I click the mouse inside or outside of the control. The control works fine on its demo website but something goes wrong when I use it on my page. Any idea what could be causing this? I am using JQuery 1.6.2-min. If I click on both the buttons, both starts moving with the mouse and value keeps changing in the textbox. How to release this capture or identify the problem?

[Here the link to DateTimePicker I am using](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Code I am using:

```
            $("#txtDateTime").datetimepicker({
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonImage: 'images/calendar.png',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm',
            ampm: true
        });
```

Comment: Can you share some code you are using or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or link of your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was because of [jCorners](http://jcorners.culturezoo.com/) script added inside the master file.